Existence of right inverse implies "full"?
I have read that a functor $F:C\to D$ which has a right-inverse $G:D\to C$ (i.e. a functor $G$ such that $F\circ G=Id_D$) must be a "full" functor, i.e. surjective on hom sets which means that the map
$$
\varphi_{X,Y}\colon Hom_C(X,Y) \to Hom_D(F(X), F(Y))
$$
given by $F$ is surjective for all $X,Y\in C$.

Why is this the case?

I can show this only for homomorphisms $G(d):G(Z)\to G(W)$ in the set $Hom_C(X,Y)$ for $d:Z\to W$ in $Hom_D(Z, W)$. What is also clear is that $F$ is surjective on objects.

Any $d : FX \to FY$ is the image of $Gd : GFX \to GFY$, since $FGd = d : FX \to FY$.

@NaïmFavier give your response as an answer below!

@NaïmFavier Full means that for every $X$ and $Y$ in $C$, every $h\in \mathrm{Hom}(F(X),F(Y))$ is the image of some $u\in\mathrm{Hom}_C(X,Y)$. It is not immediate that $G(d)$ is in the required Hom set.

You're right... is this even true? I think the inclusion of ${a \to b}$ into ${a \to b; c; d}$ has a non-full left inverse mapping $c$ to $a$ and $d$ to $b$. It seems like you can only show that $F$ is full on $G$'s image.

As written, the claim is false.
Let $\mathsf{C}$ be the category with three objects $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and a single arrow $X\to Y$ (plus the identity arrows). Let $\mathsf{D}$ be the category with two objects $A$ and $B$, and a single arrow $A\to B$ (plus the identity arrows). Let $G\colon\mathsf{D}\to \mathsf{C}$ be given by sending $A$ to $X$, $B$ to $Y$. Let $F\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}$  send $X$ to $A$, $Y$ to $B$, and $Z$ to $A$.
Since the only compositions we can perform involve either two identity arrows, or the unique non-identity arrow with an identity arrow, these are functors.
In addition, $F(G(A)) = F(X) = A$, $F(G(B))=F(Y)=B$, $F(G(\mathrm{id}_A))=\mathrm{id}_A$, $F(G(\mathrm{id}_B))=\mathrm{id}_B$. And since $F$ takes the unique arrow in $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X,Y)$ to the unique arrow in $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(A,B)$, it follows that $F\circ G$ applied to this arrow yields the arrow as well. Thus, $F\circ G=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathsf{D}}$.
However, $F$ is not full. For $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X,Z)$ is empty, whereas $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(F(X),F(Z)) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(A,A) = \{\mathrm{id}_A\}$, so you cannot have a surjective map between $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X,Z)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(F(X),F(Z))$.
What is true is that the restriction of $F$ to the image of $G$ is full: If $C_1=G(D_1)$ and $C_2\in G(D_2)$ are objects in the image of $G$, and $h\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(F(C_1),F(C_2))=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{D}}(D_1,D_2)$, then $G(h)\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(G(D_1),G(D_2))=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(C_1,C_2)$, and $F(G(h))=h$.

Thank you. So Exercise 6 here is not correct, right?:
http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~temkin/teach/math598/2013/HW9.pdf

@mrpotato: That problem is about essentially right inverses, which require $F\circ G$ to be isomorphic to the identity functor, not equal to the identity functor. Different problems!

Even so, the counterexample has $F \circ G \simeq \text{Id}_D$, so it still applies.

@NaïmFavier Fair enough, but still.

Sorry, I don't understand: For the direction I asked for, isomorphy to id follows from equal to id. So the exercise is "false" due to your counterexample, right?

@mrpotato Yes, but there are some issues. I suspect the "full and essentially surjective" should just be modified or interpreted as something along the final paragraph.
